# How to split an audio file into 1 second long chunks of audio files in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, audio, split, chunks

How do you split an audio file into 1 second long chunks (frames) of audio files in Matlab?
Anything helps really, excuse my ignorance as I am not very experienced with Matlab...
I have tried

```
clear all; close all;
[y, fs] = audioread('red.wav'); 
chunk_size = fs*1;
```

but then stuck.

Comment: ... but what have you tried so far and where exactly did that fail?

Comment: I thought it would be a very simple code to read the file and write it into smaller chunks...I am short of a code to specify the chunk size in either samples or seconds for wavwrite function...thanks

Comment: See: [MATLAB's colon operator](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colon.html) and/or [`reshape`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use audioread to read the file in chunks instead of reading the entire file in all at once. The code below might be helpful.

```
info = audioinfo('handel.wav');

Fs = info.SampleRate;
chunkDuration = 1; % 1 sec
numSamplesPerChunk = chunkDuration*Fs;

chunkCnt = 1;
for startLoc = 1:numSamplesPerChunk:info.TotalSamples
    endLoc = min(startLoc + numSamplesPerChunk - 1, info.TotalSamples);

    y = audioread('handel.wav', [startLoc endLoc]);
    outFileName = sprintf('outfile%03d.wav', chunkCnt);
    audiowrite(outFileName, y, Fs);
    chunkCnt = chunkCnt + 1;
end
```

Hope this helps.

Dinesh

Comment: awsome, very simple and efficient solution, beautifully coded , thanks Dinesh.

Answer (score 2):

you can do it with a for loop, something like:

```
[y, fs] = audioread('red.wav'); 
for t = 0:floor(size(y,2)/fs)-1
    z = y(t*fs+1:(t+1)*fs)
    filename = ['output' num2str(t)];
    wavwrite(z,fs,filename)
end
```

This should write every (except the last) second in y and save it as output1...outputt. In the loop form, the last second which might not be a whole second but 0.5 or 0.7 of a second could break the loop, so you will have to write another line to get the last second.

This is not an efficient approach for long files! Look at reshape for more efficient approach